tel protocol not supported in Telegram WebApp
I am trying to use a tel protocol in my Telegram WebApp, but getting an error [Telegram.WebApp] Url protocol is not supported tel:+1234567. I know it means that the web view of Telegram is not supporting tel protocols yet, but are there any workarounds for that?
const dialPhone = () => {
        window.location.href = `tel:+14231231`;
    }

I tried to use Telegram.WebApp.openLink but it didn't help.

Using window.open resolved the issue
